# Option and command key are switched for a keyboard on my mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

I just connected a keyboard I haven't used in a while. For some reason the option and command keys are suddenly switched.

I went into settings > Keyboard > Modifier Keys and everything is at default (nothing is swapped). I need to swap them in the modifier keys setting in order for them to be unswapped (i.e. I need to set cmd -> opt and opt -> cmd in the settings in order for cmd = cmd and opt = opt).

I'm on macos monterey 12.2.1 and use a ERGO K860 Keyboard.

Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem with 12.2.1 and my ERGO K860 keyboard.
The problem started when I updated from 12.2.0 to 12.2.1.

Every time I reboot, I have to change the Modifier Keys.
I have a different Mac running 12.2.1 and it works fine with the same keyboard!

Answer (score 26):

Long press fn+o (3 seconds) to switch your keyboard layout to mac os.
https://defkey.com/logitech-pop-keys-shortcuts#105067

Comment: the hell, how was I supposed to know this?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

When you fix the modifier keys, is it durable? (I.E. you don’t have to make the change each time you disconnect / reconnect this and only this Keyboard)

System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys

[image: Monterey Modifier Keys settings on macOS]

I’ve never needed to [retrigger the “identify this keyboard” setup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/415045/5472), but the OS should try to remember each keyboard unless the cable or USB controller board on the keyboard has changed or broken (re-flashed / updated / failure)

Comment: What do you mean by durable? Btw I just tested the keyboard by connecting it to another computer and it works as normal for that one.

Comment: If you set it on this mac, does it stick?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/180728/85275 I managed to launch the settings app on one Mac but not another - I can't figure out why as yet. Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/379907/85275 to force recognition.